# How to exclude App.config from getting bundled in the .exe in a .net core 3 single-file self-contained WinForms app?

Tags: winforms, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have a Winforms .NET Core 3 app that I want to publish as a Self-Contained Single-File Deployment

Here is the relevant `.csproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--PackageReferences-->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--ProjectReferences-->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I am using `<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` so it generates a Self Contained Deployment for Windows x64 and `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>` so everything gets embedded in the `.exe` file.

When publishing by running:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

I get the `.exe` and the `.pdb` files at `bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\win-x64\publish`

```
- MyApp.exe
- MyApp.pdb
```

What do I need to change in the `.csproj` file so I get the `MyApp.dll.config` or `MyApp.exe.config` whichever is correct next to the `.exe` so the app actually reads config from it instead of its embedded `App.Config`?

I have tried adding this

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="*.config">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

as hinted by this link [Single-file Publish - Build System Interface](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/single-file/design.md#build-system-interface) but it still produces only the two files.

Comment: 1) .NET Core doesn't use `.config` files, it uses any configuration mechanism you set up in `Startup`. Using `appsettings.json` etc is just a built-in default. You could easily use ini or XML files

Comment: 2) All files are already contained in the `.exe` file. This file is a package and bootstrapper that upacks everything to a specific folder the first time it runs and then calls the decompressed files, including any files marked as `content`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Forgot to mention that this has been migrated from a .NET Framework WIndows Forms app that is currently using the App.Config and still works. There is no Startup file, and even if I change it to use appsettings.json I still need it to be outside of the .exe file

Comment: Since I experimented with this option myself: how does your exe find the config file? In my case I excluded appsettings.json and now the exe gets extracted to a temp directory and does not find the file anymore.

Answer (score 16):

Your question helped me figure out this for me, so thanks.
hopefully this works for you too.

my .csproj looks like

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

just done some further testing with a .config file

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="*.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

that worked for me, with the other config from above.

Comment: And here's a relevant documentation (sort of), which refers to the forementioned `ExcludeFromSingleFile` option: https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/single-file/design_3_0.md